# iptables: how to redirect outgoing traffic to a given IP to a loopback

Tags: iptables

I would like to know if the following is possible, and how to do that with iptables. We are looking at a stand alone Linux system, not a router. For all traffic this system sends to 10.9.9.9, that traffic should instead go to 127.0.0.10.

Things should be configured so that answers from 127.0.0.10 (a service internal to the system, simulating 10.9.9.9's expected behaviour) do come back as answers from 10.9.9.9 ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but it should work like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -j DNAT -d 10.9.9.9 --to-destination 127.0.0.10
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT -s 127.0.0.10 --to-source 10.9.9.9
```

Note: This replaces the sourceip of all packets comming from 127.0.0.10 (not just the answers to incomming packets)